# Проблема с аргументом callback_data в боте Телеграмма Python

Tags: python, telebot, callback

Собственно, писал простой код для бота в ТГ, просто для упрощения работы с информацией, в одном из топиков сайта посоветовали использовать callback, вроде все написал по примеру, но, в итоге,  получил ошибки в аргументе

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot()

f=open('admins.txt')
List = open('list.txt', 'rb+')
line_count = sum(1 for line in List)
List.seek(0)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Авторизация\nВведите код для админов')

@bot.message_handler()
def base1(message):
    if message.text == '123456':
        
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)

        zap = types.KeyboardButton('Записи', callback_data = 'zap')
        clients = types.KeyboardButton('Клиенты', callback_data = 'clients')
        freeclass = types.KeyboardButton('Свободные классы', callback_data = 'freeclass')
        Check = types.KeyboardButton('Проверка',callback_data = 'check')

        markup.add(zap, clients, freeclass, Check)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Функции:', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'zap':
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
        classes = types.KeyboardButton('Классы')
        back = types.KeyboardButton('Вернуться', callback_data == 'back')
        markup1.add(classes, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, List, reply_markup=markup1)
    elif call.data == 'clients':
        markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        back = types.KeyboardButton('Вернуться',callback_data == 'back')
        markup1.add(back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'В доработке' , reply_markup=markup2)                 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def answer1(call):
    if call.data == 'back':
        base1(massege)
bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval=0)
```

Код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bot\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1047, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1122, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1078, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 154, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 98, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6086, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "C:\bot\main.py", line 20, in base1
    zap = types.KeyboardButton('Записи', callback_data = 'zap')
TypeError: KeyboardButton.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback_data'
```

Проблема в том, что все части должны быть взаимосвязанные между собой, переходы между КБ должны быть и прописывать каждой по пути через message не выйдет.

Comment: Зачем вы в keyboard button пихает колбек дату? Колбек дата есть только у InlineKeyboardButton. У обычной клавиатуры такого нет

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать callback кнопки для них нужно использовать клавиатуру

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
```

Для создания кнопок используйте

```
types.InlineKeyboardButton
```